# How do I intrepret the generated motifs of a dataset of 5-methylcytosine (5mC) sequences?

Tags: methylation, motifs

I'm a computer science person currently working on a project which uses deep learning to identify 5mC sites of Nipponbare Rice. Within the project, there is an option to view what the model 'discovers' through the generated motifs. Here are the motifs generated by most of the models

[image]
[image]
[image]

with the most common motif of being ACGGC. I've also read [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8809349/?fbclid=IwAR3h6riHhb22Z1mvtxduA7kkzPvmcmzbIK7zXFc4aN-OqOMsatP6BmulN5I) which states that

> Alignment of the 5mC methylation sites indicated the conserved dinucleotide CG in the center with less conserved flanking bases.

and

> The 5mC motif was similar to the methylation motif 5′-CmCGG-3′ of NgoAXIV in Neisseria gonorrhoeae.

Am I correct in assuming that the model has 'discovered' something that has been in the literature, specifically the CG motif? Also, how do I make sense of the second statement in terms of the connection of the identified motif in rice and in a bacteria?